# function pointer inside class

Tags: c++, function-pointers, typedef

I need a switch for different functions to circumvent frequent if-directions. It should work similar to the following code, encapsulated in a class:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class MaxSwitch
{
public:
typedef T (MaxSwitch::*Max_P)(T,T);
Max_P fooC_P;

MaxSwitch(int Q) {
    if (Q==0)fooC_P=&MaxSwitch::MaxVal1;
    else fooC_P=&MaxSwitch::MaxVal2;
}

inline T MaxVal1(T kx,T MAX)
{
    return kx+1;
}

inline T MaxVal2(T kx,T MAX)
{
    return MAX;
}

};

 int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
int Q=atoi ( argv[1] );
MaxSwitch<int> MAXSW(Q);


int MAX=5;

for ( int kx=0;kx<MAX;kx++ ) for ( int ky=0;ky<(MAXSW.fooC_P)(kx,MAX);ky++ )
    {
        cout<<"(kx="<<kx<<", ky="<<ky<<endl;
    }

return 0;
 }
```

I have now the trivial problem that the function call (MAXSW.fooC_P)(ky,MAX) is wrong. How to do it properly?

Comment: a quick note: your naming convention for parameters  makes the code not that readable..

Comment: (Jay D is being nice with "not that readable" - I'd have said completely confusing.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MAXSW.fooC_P` is the pointer-to-member-function that you need to call, and `MAXSW` is the object you want to call it on. So you can call that function with:

```
(MAXSW.*(MAXSW.fooC_P))(ky,MAX);
```

Comment: Note that `(MAXSW.*MAXSW.fooC_P)(ky,MAX)` will also work (that is - the inner brackets are redundant).